# How to print "\a" in c++ using codelite?

Tags: c++, iostream, cout

I was trying to print `\a` but it shows nothing so I searched for this and found out it should have made a sound but it didn't either.

I am using code lite on Windows 8.

1. How to print `\a`?
2. Where is that sound?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout <<"\a";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What OS are you working on?

Comment: lol bell sounds.. where did you read that this would work? I haven't seen a computer that does this for about 15 years

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### How to produce bell sound

If you want to print `'\a'` character to produce bell sound, you are already doing it the right way.

If the system beep is disabled (depending on your OS/target system, steps to enable beep may be different), you won't hear any sound. For windows you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-disable-system-beep-windows-7) to enable the beep sound. One of the method tutorial suggests is following (For windows 7, should be more or less similar in windows 8 also)

> Device Manager **>** View menu **>** show hidden devices **>** Non-Plug and Play
>   Drivers **>** Beep **>** double click or right click and properties **>** Driver
>   tab **>** Startup **>** Type **>** Change from disabled to some other mode (system
>   for example)

Also it is a legacy method to produce system beep, modern systems may not make a noise, and may instead make a visual indication (such as flashing the screen, or do nothing at all.) (From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) Bell character)

---

#### How to print `\a` then

If you want to literally print `\a` use following

```
cout <<"\\a";
```

`\` is a delimiter character and `\a` stands for ascii alarm or bell character.

Using [escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) `\\` will print the first `\` character followed by the next `a`.

> `"\a"` is const char 2 with values `\a` and `'\0'`
>
> `"\\a"` in const char 3 with values `\`, `'a'` and `'\0'`

Further readings:
1. [String literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) in C++
2. [Escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) in C++